# IOS AVFoundation - square video

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation

What is a good way to change the format of a video?

I'm doing something like this to merge multiple videos togheter and export them using AVAssetExportSession:

```
AVMutableComposition *mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    NSError * error = nil;
    AVURLAsset *assetClip;
    AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrack;
    AVAssetTrack *clipAudioTrack;
    for (int i = [clipPaths count]-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        assetClip = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[clipPaths objectAtIndex:i] options:nil];
        clipVideoTrack = [[assetClip tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
        clipAudioTrack = [[assetClip tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];

        [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:clipVideoTrack.timeRange ofTrack:clipVideoTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&error];
        [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:clipAudioTrack.timeRange ofTrack:clipAudioTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&error];
    } 

    NSString *cachesFolder = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
    NSString *finalPath = [cachesFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self.currentFileName stringByAppendingString:@".mov"]];

    // Remove video file if it exists 
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:finalPath]) {
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:finalPath error:&error];
    }

    NSURL *lastURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalPath];

    AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    exporter.outputURL = lastURL;
    [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void){
        switch(exporter.status) {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                NSLog(@"exporting failed"); 
                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
                NSLog(@"exporting completed"); 
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"didCompleteMovieMerging" object:nil];
                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                NSLog(@"export cancelled");
                break;
        }
    }];
```

I saw that you can use

```
AVMutableVideoComposition* videoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
videoComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake(320, 320);
videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
```

instead of AVAssetExportSession, but I cannot find a way to make both of these work together.

Answer (score 3):

You can set exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition. I've never tried passing it without layerInstructions though, not sure how it will act.

Buuut even if you change rendersize, I do not think you can crop the frame with that, if that's what you are trying to achieve. In theory it will squeeze your frame into that rendersize. Maybe I'm wrong so test it.

The fastest way I was able to find so far is using AVAssetWriter and its pair of keys -- [NSString stringWithString:AVVideoScalingModeResizeAspectFill], AVVideoScalingModeKey -- that will crop to any size you pass, without the control of crop placement though

Answer (score 0):

You don't give the frame of the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer you're using to preview the video as you record it, but I'm guessing from the title of the question that it's square. You can use this value (or whatever the dimensions are that you want the video to end up at) to calculate a CGAffineTransform to apply to each track before it gets stitched into the whole.

For a good example of this in action, see:

https://github.com/carsonmcdonald/iOSVideoCameraMultiStitchExample